# Allow only a single dot point from this regular expression

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression that matches only 1 to 100 (inclusive):

```
/^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)$/
```

There are answers out there on how to allow a single dot point, but i do not have any idea how to merge it using the regex above?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/FcmMJU/1/ Should 100.9 also match?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you want to have a decimal dot? Like 12.34?

Comment: let say .1 or 1.3

Comment: Should 100.13 match? Or should it be 100.00.

Comment: No just allow a dot point that's it.

Comment: Just convert it to a float and check if it falls in your desired range.

Comment: Please provide example inputs and expected outputs. Few that match and few that doesn't match. Clearly nobody here understands what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could optionally match a dot and use a quantifier to specify the number of digits:

```
^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

The added part matches:

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\.[0-9]{1,2}` Match a dot, repeat 1-2 times a digit
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional using `?`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c88HQg/1)

Comment: Did not work it doesn't accept a dot.  if(!/^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/.test(input.value)){
      input.value = '';
    }

Comment: I expect it to allow just a single dot at the beginning or between numbers.